# Remove the time stamp from multiple date columns in select statement (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

I am currently attempting to remove the timestamp from multiple date columns. Actually most of the columns in the select statement contain dates. I would like to remove the time stamp from all the date values in my query results. Can this be done in MySQL?

select Date(column1, column2, column3...) FROM ... does not seem to work.
select DATE (column1), DATE(column2), DATE(column3).... doesn't seem to work either

```
SELECT 
col1,
col2,
col3, //this is a date field
col4  //this is a date field
FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT 
col1,
col2, //this is a date field
col3, //this is a date field
col4 //this is a date field
FROM table2
```

All date values should not include time stamp

Comment: Have you looked into the [`date() function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)? You'd use `date(col3), date(col4)`

Comment: Using `DATE()` should work here.  How does it not work?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The date(col1), date(col2) format actully works but "date(col1)" now becomes the column header in the export which is not not preferred.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to just use the `DATE()` function, along with an alias for whatever you want each cast column to be called:

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    DATE(col3) AS col3,
    DATE(col4) AS col4
FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT
    col1,
    DATE(col2) AS col2,
    DATE(col3) AS col3,
    DATE(col4) AS col4
FROM table2;
```

Comment: Thanks. This method also solved the column header issue

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way uses `date()`:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       DATE(col3) as col3, //this is a date field
       DATE(col4) as col4  //this is a date field
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2,
       DATE(col3) as col3, //this is a date field
       DATE(col4) as col4  //this is a date field
FROM table2;
```

You can also use `CAST(col3 as DATE)`.

Or, if the problem is that you still see the time component even when looking at the results, you can convert to a string:

```
DATE_FORMAT(col3, '%Y-%m-%d')
```